# Integral representation of Thomas-Fermi Equation

Tags: mathematical-physics

The Thomas-Fermi equation with dimensionless variables is identified as;
$$
\frac{d^2\phi}{dx^2} = \frac{\phi^{3/2}}{x^{1/2}}
$$
with the boundary conditions as
$$
\phi(0) = 1 \\
\phi(\infty) = 0.
$$
There are many series approximation solutions available to this equation. I am interested in finding the integral representation for the solution of this differential equation. Are there any literature sources available in this direction?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/806472/11127

Answer (score 1):

You have lectures notes on Density Functional Theory by Andrei Postnikov that may answer your question, in particular chapter 1 eq (1.16) http://www.home.uni-osnabrueck.de/apostnik/lectures.html it is